# Getting the alt attribute of images an adding this in new div

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, image, attr

I have a slider and I try to create a new div over every image in my slider which should show the alt attribute of each image.
I only managed to get the alt text of the first image which than appears over every image, but every image has it’s own alt text..so this is not the solution I needed.. I tried to find the correct solution but got stucked at this point..

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("<div class='image_title'></div>").insertAfter(".et_pb_gallery_image .et_overlay");
    var title = $(".et_pb_gallery_image img").attr("alt");
    $(".image_title").text(title);
});
```

I also tried this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("<div class='image_title'></div>").insertAfter(".et_pb_gallery_image .et_overlay");
    $(".image_title").each(function(){    
        var levelArray = $(".et_pb_gallery_image img").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("alt");
    }).get();
    $( ".image_title" ).html(title);
    });
});
```

But this shows every alt text on every image ...

I use wordpress with a theme which has an built in content image slider > but the build in slider only shows titel and alt attribute only when the lightbox is shown/pops up. I want the alt text to be visible on the images, thats what I am trying to do.

HTML Snippet of how the slider looks in the html page:

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="post_gallery">
      <div class="gallery_item">
          <div class="et_pb_gallery_image">
              <a href="#" title="image title 01">
                 <img src="image.jpg" alt="Pic 01">
                 <span class="et_overlay"></span>
                 <!-- this is created with the code I used -->
                 <div class="image_title">Pic 01</div>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="post_gallery">
      <div class="gallery_item">
          <div class="et_pb_gallery_image">
              <a href="#" title="image title 02">
                 <img src="image.jpg" alt="Pic 02">
                 <!-- but the second image also has "Pic 01" instead of "Pic 02" -->
                 <div class="image_title">Pic 01</div>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you got the HTML you are using as well please?

Comment: Could you add some HTML code with the example of just one div with its image?

Comment: @Ash I did add HTML snippet

Comment: @kar sorry i viewed it before you added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".et_pb_gallery_image .et_overlay").each(function(){
  $("<div class='image_title'></div>").insertAfter(this);
  var thisImage = $(this).parents('.et_pb_gallery_image').find('img');
  var title = thisImage.attr('alt');
  $(this).siblings('.image_title').html(title);
});
```